# Cannot pip install Pillow 7 on Python 3.9

Tags: pip, python-imaging-library

I'm facing an issue that I can't find a solution for it.
I have Python 3.9.0a1 and pip 20.0.2  and I can't install different packages like Pillow while with other packages I don't have this issue, someone can help me to manage this error? Is it an issue related to the version of Python?

Error:

```
C:\Users\aless>pip install Pillow
Collecting Pillow
  Using cached Pillow-7.0.0.tar.gz (38.2 MB)
Installing collected packages: Pillow
    Running setup.py install for Pillow ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\aless\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\aless\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-1nsui_69\\Pillow\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\aless\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-1nsui_69\\Pillow\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\aless\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-wuxivqzq\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\aless\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\Include\Pillow'
         cwd: C:\Users\aless\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1nsui_69\Pillow\
    Complete output (176 lines):
    C:\Users\aless\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1nsui_69\Pillow\setup.py:42: RuntimeWarning: Pillow 7.0.0 does not support Python 3.9 and does not provide prebuilt Windows binaries. We do not recommend building from source on Windows.
      warnings.warn(
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win32-3.9
    creating build\lib.win32-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\BdfFontFile.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\BlpImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\BmpImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\BufrStubImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ContainerIO.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\CurImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\DcxImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\DdsImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\EpsImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ExifTags.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\features.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\FitsStubImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\FliImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\FontFile.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\FpxImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\FtexImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\GbrImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\GdImageFile.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\GifImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\GimpGradientFile.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\GimpPaletteFile.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\GribStubImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\Hdf5StubImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\IcnsImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\IcoImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\Image.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageChops.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageCms.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageColor.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageDraw.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageDraw2.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageEnhance.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageFile.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageFilter.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageFont.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageGrab.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageMath.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageMode.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageMorph.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageOps.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImagePalette.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImagePath.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageQt.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageSequence.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageShow.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageStat.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageTk.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageTransform.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImageWin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\ImtImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\IptcImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\Jpeg2KImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\JpegImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\JpegPresets.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\McIdasImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\MicImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\MpegImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\MpoImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\MspImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\PaletteFile.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\PalmImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\PcdImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\PcfFontFile.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\PcxImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\PdfImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\PdfParser.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\PixarImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\PngImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\PpmImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\PsdImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\PSDraw.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\PyAccess.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\SgiImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\SpiderImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\SunImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\TarIO.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\TgaImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\TiffImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\TiffTags.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\WalImageFile.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\WebPImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\WmfImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\XbmImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\XpmImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\XVThumbImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\_binary.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\_tkinter_finder.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\_util.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\_version.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\PIL
    copying src\PIL\__main__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\PIL
    running egg_info
    writing src\Pillow.egg-info\PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to src\Pillow.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
    writing top-level names to src\Pillow.egg-info\top_level.txt
    reading manifest file 'src\Pillow.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    warning: no files found matching '*.c'
    warning: no files found matching '*.h'
    warning: no files found matching '*.sh'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.appveyor.yml'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.coveragerc'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.codecov.yml'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.editorconfig'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.readthedocs.yml'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'azure-pipelines.yml'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '.git*' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
    no previously-included directories found matching '.azure-pipelines'
    no previously-included directories found matching '.travis'
    writing manifest file 'src\Pillow.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    running build_ext


    The headers or library files could not be found for zlib,
    a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.

    Please see the install instructions at:
       https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\aless\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1nsui_69\Pillow\setup.py", line 852, in <module>
        setup(
      File "c:\users\aless\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 144, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "c:\users\aless\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "c:\users\aless\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "c:\users\aless\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "c:\users\aless\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py", line 61, in run
        return orig.install.run(self)
      File "c:\users\aless\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 545, in run
        self.run_command('build')
      File "c:\users\aless\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "c:\users\aless\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "c:\users\aless\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
        self.run_command(cmd_name)
      File "c:\users\aless\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "c:\users\aless\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "c:\users\aless\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 340, in run
        self.build_extensions()
      File "C:\Users\aless\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1nsui_69\Pillow\setup.py", line 687, in build_extensions
        raise RequiredDependencyException(f)
    __main__.RequiredDependencyException: zlib

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\aless\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1nsui_69\Pillow\setup.py", line 907, in <module>
        raise RequiredDependencyException(msg)
    __main__.RequiredDependencyException:

    The headers or library files could not be found for zlib,
    a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.

    Please see the install instructions at:
       https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html


    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\aless\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\aless\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-1nsui_69\\Pillow\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\aless\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-1nsui_69\\Pillow\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\aless\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-wuxivqzq\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\aless\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\Include\Pillow' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html doesn't list 3.9, but also mentions zlib not being found, could try installing it, or wait to see if pillow adds 3.9 support/supports it

Comment: @Thomas__ thank you, I will probably install again python 3.8.

Answer (score 6):

As @Njord mentioned, PIL is not maintained. Its fork, Pillow, is. [Here's information about the project.](https://python-pillow.org/) The fork is not yet updated for Python 3.9 - as many packages will not be. You'll need to use Python 3.8 in the meantime until the update comes.

Pillow will get Python 3.9 support in its 8.0.0 release. As of today, it's [scheduled for October 15, 2020](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/4953).

Comment: Yep, there's a warning up at the top explaining: `RuntimeWarning: Pillow 7.0.0 does not support Python 3.9 and does not provide prebuilt Windows binaries. We do not recommend building from source on Windows.`

Comment: Pillow 8.0.0 supporting Python 3.9 is out now! https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/releasenotes/8.0.0.html

Comment: It is Sep 2021 and am having this issue with Python 3.8.9 and 3.9.4 and Pillow 8.3.1. Previous comments do not mention which minor versions actually work, has this issue been reintroduced or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

The reason this is happening is because PIL hasn't updated to Python 3.9 yet, I am not aware of any fixes but right now it is best to downgrade to a Python version that can run PIL.

[image]

You aren't alone in this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. This can be solved by cloning gym from github. I used GIT CMD app for cloning

```
    git clone https://github.com/openai/gym.git

    cd gym

    pip install -e .
```

[ In My windows 10 laptop

Python 3.9.5 (tags/v3.9.5:0a7dcbd, May  3 2021, 17:27:52) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32

Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

`import pil # note not PIL for importing pillow`

`pil.__version__`

'8.2.0'

`import gym`

`gym.__version__`

'0.18.0'
]

Image:
[image: 1]