# I am trying to install pillow using 'pip install Pillow' but I am getting error

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

```
Error:       
    `(env) E:\Python Projects\Flask\Flask Blog>pip install pillow
        Collecting pillow
          Using cached Pillow-7.2.0.tar.gz (39.1 MB)
        Building wheels for collected packages: pillow
          Building wheel for pillow (setup.py) ... error
          ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
           command: 'e:\python projects\flask\env\scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Gaming\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-boxgam9w\\pillow\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Gaming\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-boxgam9w\\pillow\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\Gaming\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-xk_48jkq'
               cwd: C:\Users\Gaming\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-boxgam9w\pillow\
          Complete output (172 lines):
          C:\Users\Gaming\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-boxgam9w\pillow\setup.py:42: RuntimeWarning: Pillow 7.2.0 does not support Python 3.9 and does not provide prebuilt Windows binaries. We do not recommend building from source on Windows.
            warnings.warn(
          running bdist_wheel
          running build
          running build_py
          creating build
          creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
          creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
          copying src\PIL\BdfFontFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
          copying src\PIL\BlpImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL...
          ...


          warning: no previously-included files matching '.git*' found anywhere in distribution
          warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
          warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
          no previously-included directories found matching '.ci'
          writing manifest file 'src\Pillow.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
          running build_ext
        
        
          The headers or library files could not be found for zlib,
          a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.
        
          Please see the install instructions at:
             https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html
        
          Traceback (most recent call last):
            File "C:\Users\Gaming\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-boxgam9w\pillow\setup.py", line 864, in <module>
              setup(
            File "e:\python projects\flask\env\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 153, in setup
              return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
            File "C:\Users\Gaming\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup...
              ...
              ...
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
          Traceback (most recent call last):
            File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
            File "C:\Users\Gaming\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-boxgam9w\pillow\setup.py", line 918, in <module>
              raise RequiredDependencyException(msg)
          __main__.RequiredDependencyException:
        
          The headers or library files could not be found for zlib,
          a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.
        
          Please see the install instructions at:
             https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html
        
        
          ----------------------------------------
          ERROR: Failed building wheel for pillow
          Running setup.py clean for pillow
        Failed to build pillow
        Installing collected packages: pillow
            Running setup.py install for pillow ... error
            ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
             command: 'e:\python projects\flask\env\scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Gaming\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-boxgam9w\\pillow\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Gaming\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-boxgam9w\\pillow\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Gaming\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-8oe6sa1m\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'e:\python projects\flask\env\include\site\python3.9\pillow'
                 cwd: C:\Users\Gaming\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-boxgam9w\pillow\
            Complete output (174 lines):
            C:\Users\Gaming\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-boxgam9w\pillow\setup.py:42: RuntimeWarning: Pillow 7.2.0 does not support Python 3.9 and does not provide prebuilt Windows binaries. We do not recommend building from source on Windows.
              warnings.warn(
            running install
            running build
            running build_py
            creating build
            creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
            creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
            copying src\PIL\BdfFontFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
            copying src\PIL\BlpImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
            copying src\PIL\BmpImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
            copying src\PIL\BufrStubImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
            copying src\PIL\ContainerIO.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
            copying src\PIL\CurImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL...
            ...


            warning: no files found matching '*.h'
            warning: no files found matching '*.sh'
            warning: no previously-included files found matching '.appveyor.yml'
            warning: no previously-included files found matching '.coveragerc'
            warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
            no previously-included directories found matching '.ci'
            writing manifest file 'src\Pillow.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
            running build_ext
        
        
            The headers or library files could not be found for zlib,
            a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.
        
            Please see the install instructions at:
               https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html
        
            Traceback (most recent call last):
              File "C:\Users\Gaming\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-boxgam9w\pillow\setup.py", line 864, in <module>
                setup(
              File "e:\python projects\flask\env\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 153, in setup
                return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)...
               ...

        
            Traceback (most recent call last):
              File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
              File "C:\Users\Gaming\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-boxgam9w\pillow\setup.py", line 918, in <module>
                raise RequiredDependencyException(msg)
            __main__.RequiredDependencyException:
        
            The headers or library files could not be found for zlib,
            a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.
        
            Please see the install instructions at:
               https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html
        
        
            ----------------------------------------
        ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'e:\python projects\flask\env\scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Gaming\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-boxgam9w\\pillow\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Gaming\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-boxgam9w\\pillow\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Gaming\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-8oe6sa1m\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'e:\python projects\flask\env\include\site\python3.9\pillow' Check the logs for full command output.`
```

I am begginer in Flask and i am getting this error while installation.
My pip version is 20.2.3.
My python version is 3.9.
I also try to install Pillow using `pip install PIL` but it doesn't work anyway.
I am using Windows 10.
So can you please help me to install Pillow using pip.

Comment: Did you follow the instructions that it tells you to at https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Issues with Python 3.9 and pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60590809/issues-with-python-3-9-and-pip)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is not very clear but is shown on the first line of the "complete output (172 lines)":

> C:\Users\Gaming\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-boxgam9w\pillow\setup.py:42: RuntimeWarning: Pillow 7.2.0 does not support Python 3.9 and does not provide prebuilt Windows binaries. We do not recommend building from source on Windows.

Pillow 8.0.0 is due out next week and will support Python 3.9.

See:

- https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/4953
- https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/4764

**Edit: Pillow 8.0.0 supporting Python 3.9 is out now!** https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/releasenotes/8.0.0.html