# Problem with installation of pillow in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, installation, python-imaging-library, setup.py

I am trying to install pillow in windows x64 with python 3.9. Witout pillow, unfortunately, i can't install matplotlib.

When I do:

> pip install pillow

I get this error:

> ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
> command: 'c:\program files\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] =
> '"'"'C:\Users\Luca\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-h61p2lkf\pillow\setup.py'"'"';
> **file**='"'"'C:\Users\Luca\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-h61p2lkf\pillow\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize,
> '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"',
> '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))'
> bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\Luca\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-bymckwkk'
> cwd: C:\Users\Luca\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-h61p2lkf\pillow
> Complete output (172 lines):
> C:\Users\Luca\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-h61p2lkf\pillow\setup.py:42:
> RuntimeWarning: Pillow 7.2.0 does not support Python 3.9 and does not
> provide prebuilt Windows binaries. We do not recommend building from
> source on Windows.
> warnings.warn(
> running bdist_wheel
> running build
> running build_py
> creating build
> creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
> creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
> copying src\PIL\BdfFontFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
> copying src\PIL\BlpImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
> copying src\PIL\BmpImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
> copying src\PIL\BufrStubImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
> copying src\PIL\ContainerIO.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
> copying src\PIL\CurImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
> copying src\PIL\DcxImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
> copying src\PIL\DdsImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
> copying src\PIL\EpsImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
> copying src\PIL\ExifTags.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
> copying src\PIL\features.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
> copying src\PIL\FitsStubImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
> copying src\PIL\FliImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
> copying src\PIL\FontFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
> copying src\PIL\FpxImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
> copying src\PIL\FtexImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
> copying src\PIL\GbrImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
> copying src\PIL\GdImageFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
> copying src\PIL\GifImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
> copying src\PIL\GimpGradientFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
> copying src\PIL\GimpPaletteFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
> copying src\PIL\GribStubImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
> copying src\PIL\Hdf5StubImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
> copying src\PIL\IcnsImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
> copying src\PIL\IcoImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
> copying src\PIL\Image.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
> copying src\PIL\ImageChops.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
> copying src\PIL\ImageCms.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
> copying src\PIL\ImageColor.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
> copying src\PIL\ImageDraw.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
> copying src\PIL\ImageDraw2.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
> copying src\PIL\ImageEnhance.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
> copying src\PIL\ImageFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
> copying src\PIL\ImageFilter.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
> copying src\PIL\ImageFont.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
> copying src\PIL\ImageGrab.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
> copying src\PIL\ImageMath.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
> copying src\PIL\ImageMode.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
> copying src\PIL\ImageMorph.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
> copying src\PIL\ImageOps.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
> copying src\PIL\ImagePalette.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
> copying src\PIL\ImagePath.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
> copying src\PIL\ImageQt.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
> copying src\PIL\ImageSequence.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
> copying src\PIL\ImageShow.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
> copying src\PIL\ImageStat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
> copying src\PIL\ImageTk.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
> copying src\PIL\ImageTransform.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
> copying src\PIL\ImageWin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
> copying src\PIL\ImImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
> copying src\PIL\ImtImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
> copying src\PIL\IptcImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
> copying src\PIL\Jpeg2KImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
> copying src\PIL\JpegImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
> copying src\PIL\JpegPresets.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
> copying src\PIL\McIdasImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
> copying src\PIL\MicImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
> copying src\PIL\MpegImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
> copying src\PIL\MpoImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
> copying src\PIL\MspImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
> copying src\PIL\PaletteFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
> copying src\PIL\PalmImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
> copying src\PIL\PcdImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
> copying src\PIL\PcfFontFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
> copying src\PIL\PcxImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
> copying src\PIL\PdfImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
> copying src\PIL\PdfParser.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
> copying src\PIL\PixarImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
> copying src\PIL\PngImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
> copying src\PIL\PpmImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
> copying src\PIL\PsdImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
> copying src\PIL\PSDraw.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
> copying src\PIL\PyAccess.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
> copying src\PIL\SgiImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
> copying src\PIL\SpiderImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
> copying src\PIL\SunImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
> copying src\PIL\TarIO.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
> copying src\PIL\TgaImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
> copying src\PIL\TiffImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
> copying src\PIL\TiffTags.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
> copying src\PIL\WalImageFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
> copying src\PIL\WebPImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
> copying src\PIL\WmfImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
> copying src\PIL\XbmImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
> copying src\PIL\XpmImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
> copying src\PIL\XVThumbImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
> copying src\PIL_binary.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
> copying src\PIL_tkinter_finder.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
> copying src\PIL_util.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
> copying src\PIL_version.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
> copying src\PIL_*init*_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
> copying src\PIL_*main*_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\PIL
> running egg_info
> writing src\Pillow.egg-info\PKG-INFO
> writing dependency_links to src\Pillow.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
> writing top-level names to src\Pillow.egg-info\top_level.txt
> reading manifest file 'src\Pillow.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
> reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
> warning: no files found matching '*.c'
> warning: no files found matching '*.h'
> warning: no files found matching '*.sh'
> warning: no previously-included files found matching '.appveyor.yml'
> warning: no previously-included files found matching '.coveragerc'
> warning: no previously-included files found matching '.editorconfig'
> warning: no previously-included files found matching '.readthedocs.yml'
> warning: no previously-included files found matching 'codecov.yml'
> warning: no previously-included files matching '.git*' found anywhere in distribution
> warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
> warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
> no previously-included directories found matching '.ci'
> writing manifest file 'src\Pillow.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
> running build_ext
> The headers or library files could not be found for zlib,
> a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.
>
> ```
>   Please see the install instructions at:
>      https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html
>
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\Luca\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-h61p2lkf\pillow\setup.py",
> ```
>
> line 864, in 
> setup(
> File "c:\program files\python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools_*init*_.py", line 153, in
> setup
> return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
> File "c:\program files\python39\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
> dist.run_commands()
> File "c:\program files\python39\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
> self.run_command(cmd)
> File "c:\program files\python39\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
> cmd_obj.run()
> File "C:\Users\Luca\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\wheel\bdist_wheel.py",
> line 290, in run
> self.run_command('build')
> File "c:\program files\python39\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
> self.distribution.run_command(command)
> File "c:\program files\python39\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
> cmd_obj.run()
> File "c:\program files\python39\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
> self.run_command(cmd_name)
> File "c:\program files\python39\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
> self.distribution.run_command(command)
> File "c:\program files\python39\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
> cmd_obj.run()
> File "c:\program files\python39\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 340, in run
> self.build_extensions()
> File "C:\Users\Luca\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-h61p2lkf\pillow\setup.py",
> line 694, in build_extensions
> raise RequiredDependencyException(f)
> **main**.RequiredDependencyException: zlib
>
> ```
>   During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
>     File "C:\Users\Luca\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-h61p2lkf\pillow\setup.py",
> ```
>
> line 918, in 
> raise RequiredDependencyException(msg)
> **main**.RequiredDependencyException:
>
> ```
>   The headers or library files could not be found for zlib,
>   a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.
>
>   Please see the install instructions at:
>      https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html
>
>
>   ----------------------------------------
>   ERROR: Failed building wheel for pillow
> ```

I tried to follow all of advice that i found here, but it continues to generate the error.

Who can help me, please?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Issues with Python 3.9 and pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60590809/issues-with-python-3-9-and-pip)

Comment: Pillow 8.0.0 supporting Python 3.9 is out now! https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/releasenotes/8.0.0.html

Answer (score 3):

Python 3.9 was released on October 5th 2020. Given that this is really recent you can expect a lot of libraries to not yet be supported.

Pillow has a ticket however for a Python 3.9 release: https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/4953 and according to the progress there you can expect it to be supported very soon. So you can either follow that ticket and wait until Pillow supports 3.9 or uninstall Python 3.9 for now and install Python 3.8.

My advice is to go with Python 3.8 as it will protect you from similar issues with other libraries. The only reason to go for the newer Python release is if you really need some of the newly introduced features.

Comment: Pillow 8.0.0 supporting Python 3.9 is out now! https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/releasenotes/8.0.0.html