# How can I solve this error of installing pil,cv2,requirements.txt?

Tags: python-imaging-library, opencv, requirements.txt, python

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYxQI.png)

I need to install pil,cv2,requirements.txt packages and many more packages but this error shows on the screen whenever I try to install it
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pil (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pil

I've also attached an image that shows the same.
Please help me with this.

Comment: which python version do you use?

Comment: python 3.9.1 and it is the latest version available

Comment: possible answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60590809/cannot-pip-install-pillow-7-on-python-3-9